# conversion of *.tif file format to *.hdr file format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, convert

I have clipped DEM of a region from SRTM data. It is in *.tif format. Now I want the same file in header format (*.hdr). How can I convert *.tif file to *.hdr file?

Comment: There is no such thing as a '.hdr' format. There is a number of file formats that consist of two files, typically one binary file with the cell values, and one text file with some parameters (number of columns, rows, extent, ...). E.g. for the 'BIL' format: 'file.bil' and 'file.hdr', but there are many more.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Raster to Float (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000006000000).

> Two outputs are created: an IEEE floating-point format 32-bit signed
>   binary file with a .flt extension and an ASCII header file with a .hdr
>   extension. Both will use the same output floating-point raster file
>   name.